# Parsing JSON encoded PHP array with Javascript - unexpected character

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using PHP to encode array to JSON string like this:

```
$price['price'] = "20";
$price = json_encode($price)
return $price;
```

so when I'm accessing the script I get this data:

```
{"price":"20"}
```

Here is my jQuery/Javascript code:

```
$("#form_pickupDate_day").change(function()
    {
        var frm = $(document.form);
        var data = JSON.stringify(frm.serializeArray());

        $.ajax
        ({
            method: "POST",
            url: "script.php",
            data: {json : data },
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(json)
            {
                var obj = JSON.parse(json);
                    $("#form_price").val(obj.price);
            }
        });
    });
```

The error I get in Firefox:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The whole point of specifying `dataType: 'json'` is that jQuery will parse the results for you. Your `json` varaible *already contains a JavaScript object*. You don't need to parse it twice.

You also shouldn't call it "json", since it's not JSON at that point:

```
success: function(data) {
  $("#form_price").val(data.price);
}
```